# How copy or display unique entries from two text files in linux or in windows

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

I have two files and the format of the files is variable=value or # or # variable.
Values of all variables is either unset;yes;mod 
I want to copy all entries from these files to another file and only keep unique entries.
In case both files have same variable but with different values. 
I would like copy the ones with =mod.
How to achieve this using awk or sed or grep or bash script ?

I usually do this manually by merging the files and copying the resulting in excel.
In excel I use the function remove duplicates in excel and then I manually remove
the entries as per above my requirements.

Comment: And what about the lines starting with `#`?

Comment: same rule applies .
copy unique entries 
ignore all # since they are comment .

Answer (score 0):

Build a program in whatever language you're most used to.
Logic:

```
While not EOF (file1)
{
    Read line from file1
    While not EOF (file2)
    {
        Read line from file2
        If l-file1 = l-file2
        {
            do nothing
        }
        Else
        {
            output unique value
        }
    }
}
```

This will compare every line of file1 to every line of file2 (instead of comparing line-to-line).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `awk` script:

```
NR==FNR { data[$1] = $2; next; }
!/#/ {
    if ($1 in data) {
        if ($1 == "mod") {
            print $0;
        } else {
            print $1 "=" data[$1];
        }
    } else {
        print $0;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f script -F= file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl one liner**

**file one:**
1
2
3

**file two:**
1
4
3

**Print Only Unique Line**
`perl -lne 'print if ++$n{ $_ } == 1 ' file_one.txt file_two.txt`

**Or**

`perl -lne 'print unless ++$n{ $_ } '  file_one.txt file_two.txt`

**output**
1
4
3
2